# Simple JQuery Expand All Collapse All Toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am expanding and collapsing divs. I also allow expand all and collapse all. The problem is if a div is already expanded, when the user clicks expand all, the expanded div will get collapsed, while the other divs will expand (and vice versa). How can I expand all the divs that are not already expanded, and collapse all the divs that are not already collapsed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle_container").hide();

    //Expand/Collapse Individual Boxes
    $("span.expand_heading").toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active"); 
        }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $("span.expand_heading").click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll(".toggle_container:first").slideToggle("slow");
    });

    //Show hide 'expand all' and 'collapse all' text
    $(".expand_all").toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass("expanded"); 
        }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("expanded");
    });

    //expand or collapse all boxes
    $(".expand_all").click(function(){
        $(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//expand or collapse all boxes
    $(".expand_all").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("expanded")){
           $(".toggle_container").slideDown("slow");
        }
        else {
           $(".toggle_container").slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
```

You could check to see if your expand_all element has the expanded class or not and slide all of your elements up or down depending.

Answer (score 2):

try limiting your selector to just hidden values:

```
$(".toggle_container:hidden").slideToggle("slow");
```

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score 0):

[.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) should do.

Answer (score 0):

A more effective and efficeint way to do this would be the following:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var panels = $('.panel-collapse.collapse');
    var collapse = function()
    {
        if (!$(this).hasClass ('open')) return;
        $(this).slideUp().removeClass('open').removeClass('active');
    };
    $(".panel-heading").click (function()
    {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (next.hasClass ('active')) return;
        panels.each (collapse);
        next.slideToggle().toggleClass('open').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

This approach takes into consideration the following points:

- Store the collapsable panels in variable `panels` so that we don't
  need to search for them everytime a header is clicked.
- When a header is clicked, if its panel is already open we don't need to do anything.
- When resetting the pannels on every click we close only the open ones and ignore the rest.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/z9a6tbya/)